# Objective-C NSString become null after loop

Tags: objective-c, pointers

C folks, I am a newbiew who just jumped into Obj-C for days. I have this question, I know maybe it is a no brainer but I did have spent a lot of time searching on the web but couldn't find relevant answer, please help here.

I am trying to write a simple n-ary tree data structure just for practice. I made a class named ICNode, in which it holds a NSMutableArray for its children, a parent and a depth.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ICNode : NSObject
{

}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id content;
@property (nonatomic, weak) ICNode *parent;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *children;     // should store ICNode
@property (nonatomic) int depth;    // root is 0, not set is -1
```

Then I wrote a simple test code to test it.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test %d", i];
    ICNode *child = [[ICNode alloc] init];
    [child setContent:string];
    [root addChild:child];
    STAssertEqualObjects([child parent], root, @"child's parent is root");
    STAssertEquals([child depth], 1, @"children's depth is 1");
}
STAssertEquals([root numberOfChildren], 2, @"root's number of children is testRun");
NSLog(@"%@", root);
```

My problem here is that in the last line of code, the NSLog, I expect to see something like this:

```
"Content: Test 1(depth=1) -> Parent: I am Root -> Children: (null)",
"Content: Test 2(depth=1) -> Parent: I am Root -> Children: (null)"
```

but instead it is always

```
"Content: (null)(depth=1) -> Parent: I am Root -> Children: (null)",
"Content: (null)(depth=1) -> Parent: I am Root -> Children: (null)"
```

I then put a breakpoint there and found out that right after the addChild method, it is find, but after the loop finishes, the content of the child will become null. I am not that familiar with pointer stuff so I suspect this is something related to pointer.

Another observation is if I do something like this,

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test %d", 1];
ICNode *child = [[ICNode alloc] initWithContent:string parent:root];
NSString *string1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test %d", 2];
ICNode *child1 = [[ICNode alloc] initWithContent:string1 parent:root];
NSLog(@"%@", [root description]);
```

Then the output is fine. But I do want to be able to create nodes using loops.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Lookup what "weak" means.  (Variable "string" has passed out of context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ICNode's `parent` and `content` properties are **weak**, they become nil as soon as the last strong reference goes away.

In the code snipit you had `content` is set from the local variable `string`, and that variable is local to the for loop.   If you move it outside the for loop into the main body of the function ICNode's `content` property won't become nil.

However it is likely that you want `content` to be a **strong,copy** property, not **weak**.